# Carpet makes Whistling Sound

Tags: flooring, carpentry, carpet

My carpet is around 5 years old. Now its starting to make a whistling sound stepping on it.
I started doing Yoga/Stretching recently with a proper yoga mat. It requires lot of deep stretch which may press down carpet.
However, The carpet looks even, so not sure what would be the case. It has carpet, padding underneath, with plywood subfloor. Does anyone know what causes the "whistling" sound? I plan to check under in a few weeks. The sound is starting to grow under a 5ft by 5ft area now

Sound: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnhWrLFYc8o

[image]

Comment: Do you have a recording/ video of the sound you could share?

Comment: hi @g491 sure, one sound is my foot tapping carpet, other sound is squeak https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnhWrLFYc8o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there's something rubbing - it could be a subfloor nail when the boards under the carpet move or even two subfloor boards rubbing against each other.

There is a special type of screw / kit that lets you secure the boards without having to pull up the carpet - the screw heads actually are able to be snapped off after you screw them in so you don't feel them.  You can look up Squeeeeek No More / Squeak-No-More to find it. I've used it before with a lot of success.